# Search based application using Elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, flask

I want to make search based application using python and elasticsearch. I want to create web application for this i will python but which framework i should use Django or Flask i don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your site provide only search facility Flask is good, as it is lightweight, easy to use framework.

But if the application is complex, require user management, multiple pages, email notification etc. better to choose Django, as it has lots of built-in features as site should have.